# Bitrix, Событие OnSaleDeliveryServiceCalculate, получить свойства заказа

Tags: битрикс, события

Одно из свойств участвует в формирование цены, пусть будет DEL_COST. Как его получить в событии OnSaleDeliveryServiceCalculate? Например, цену заказа я получаю  так:

```
$shipments = $event->getParameter('SHIPMENT')->getShipmentItemCollection();
$orderPrice = $shipments->getShipment()->getCollection()->getOrder()->getPrice();
```

Comment: Так вы в свойства заказа сохраняете DEL_COST ?

Comment: Нет, DEL_COST это свойство заказа, которое передается клиенту, значение его это сумма доставки.

Answer (score 1):

Вы же получили объект заказа, вот и из него и выдирайте значение свойства

```
$shipment = $event->getParameter('SHIPMENT');
$order = $shipment->getCollection()->getOrder();
$property = $order->getPropertyCollection()->getItemByOrderPropertyId(ТУТ_ИД_СВОЙСТВА);
$propertyValue = null;

if ($property !== null) {
    $propertyValue = $property->getValue();
}

if($propertyValue === 'Example')
{
    $price = 5000;
}
$baseResult->setDeliveryPrice($price);
$event->addResult(
    new EventResult(EventResult::SUCCESS, ['RESULT' => $baseResult])
);
```

Но тут вопрос, как вы собрались вызывать обновление страницы компонента оформления заказа после заполнение свойства? Без кастомизации это происходит при загрузке страницы, выбора метода доставки, либо оплаты.

Comment: Разработчики до меня, довольно сильно кастомизировали order.php, я не могу никакими методами или средствами получить в эвенте свойства заказа. Проблему решил занятнейшим костылем: в момент получения данных необходимые поля помещаю в $globals. Да, костыль, но перелопачивать половину системы нет желания )

Comment: Страницу обновлять не нужно. После оформления заказа клиента редиректит. Не баг. Фича.